# Azure Deployment Runtime Exception

Tags: c#, azure, deployment

I've created a web application in C#. It uses version 2.3. of the Azure SDK and when I run the app locally using the Azure Emulator it works okay. When I package and deploy to the Azure cloud I get the following exception when start page is trying to load:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I've looked in all my config files but none of them reference Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime version 2.2.0.0. Is there something else I should be looking out for?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your dependent DLLs (ie. something you have referenced in your role entry point DLL) is referencing the 2.2 version of the service runtime.  If you aren't able to find the dependent DLL then there are a few different ways to troubleshoot this.  Intellitrace is the easiest, and direct debugging on the Azure VM is the most powerful.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/10/03/troubleshooting-scenario-7-role-recycling.aspx for a walkthrough of both options.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to figure out that one of the library that I was using had a reference to version 2.2. of the SDK. Since that was the latest version of the library, I had to downgrade the Azure SDK from version 2.3 to 2.2 and it seems to work correctly.

Comment: Instead of downgrading from 2.3 to 2.2 you can do a binding redirect to redirect the library to use the 2.3 service runtime DLL.